Who to send a specific port to other and default gateway
I have server (x.x.x.10) with default gateway as x.x.x.1, but i need to make sure all trafic on port 1515/tcp, is send to x.x.x.100, which is a load-balancer
How do i configure this in a netplan setup.

Please [edit] your question and describe the structure and IP addresses of your network, maybe show a diagram or ASCII art. Make clear which system is trying to use port 1515/tcp with what source and destination address, and where the connection should go to.
